# Fingerprint-gui permission problem

Tags: 18.04, fingerprint-reader

when I run fingerprint-gui I get this error:

[image: permission error]

If I try to run the app as root I get this:
[image: empty gui]

My distro is Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit

Thanks,
Massimo

Answer (score 2):

Run the app from your terminal and prefix this to the package name:

```
sudo QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1
```

So that the command you run is:

```
sudo QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 fingerprint-gui
```